# See if the user is near a location? Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, cllocation

I would like to be-able to see if the user is in a 5 km radius of the other location in Swift 4.

For example:

```
User Location: 37.785834, -122.406417
Other Location: -117.564011, 48.302353
```

Thanks for anyone who helps!

Comment: Measure the distance between two points.

Comment: How? Is this possible in Swift 4?

Comment: You can use `CLLocation` `distance(from: CLLocation)` instance method

Comment: Can you post the code as a solution please?

Comment: `let user = CLLocation(latitude: 37.785834, longitude: -122.406417)
let other = CLLocation(latitude: 37.8, longitude: -122.5)
let distance = user.distance(from: other)  // 8391.307900456288`

Comment: Ok thanks. Ill try it now

Comment: What measurement is this? 8391.307900456288, kilometers, meters?

Comment: It's in meters. Doesn't hurt to check the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423689-distance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can detect when the user enters or leaves a geographic region automatically by using [Region Monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/monitoring_the_user_s_proximity_to_geographic_regions) feature provided by [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager).

Start monitoring the circle region around the specified coordinate:

```
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.785834, longitude: -122.406417)
// Make sure the app is authorized.
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
    // Make sure region monitoring is supported.
    if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLCircularRegion.self) {
        // Register the region.
        let maxDistance = locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance
        let region = CLCircularRegion(center: center, 
             radius: 5000.0, identifier: "YourRegionID")
        region.notifyOnEntry = true
        region.notifyOnExit = false

        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
    }
}
```

Handle a region-related notification (enter notification in this example) by implementing suitable method from [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate):

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    if let region = region as? CLCircularRegion {
        // your logic to handle region-entered notification
    }
}
```